# unable to get radio button value on a div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button

I am unable to get selected radio button value. Basically, I am facing the problem in my Html page where I want to print selected radio button values.
I want to get values on the same page in a specific div. below is my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
     function myFunction()
    {
        var input = (document.getElementById('shirt').checked)|| (document.getElementById('trouser').checked) || (document.getElementById('tshirt').checked)|| (document.getElementById('suit').checked);
        var div = document.getElementById('divID');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + input.value;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm">
    <div class="controls option block-1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 prod-left-text"> 
            <h3> Garments Type</h3>
            <p class="subtitle">Please choose your garments.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 option-value form-group">
               <label class="rad">
        <input type="radio" name="garments" value="shirt" id="shirt" onkeypress="myFunction()" >
                <div><p class="producth6">Shirt<br /><span class="producth7">Rs. 400/-</span><br /><span class="producth8">onwords</span></p>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 option-value form-group" >
                <label class="rad">
                <input type="radio" name="garments" value="trouser" id="trouser" onkeypress="myFunction()">
                    <div><p class="producth6">Trouser<br /><span class="producth7">Rs. 400/-</span><br /><span class="producth8">onwords</span></p></div>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 option-value form-group">
                <label class="rad">
                    <input type="radio" name="garments" value="Tshirt" id="tshirt" onkeypress="myFunction()">
                    <div><p class="producth6">T-shirt<br /><span class="producth7">Rs. 500/-</span><br /><span class="producth8">onwords</span></p>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 option-value form-group">
                <label class="rad">
                    <input type="radio" name="garments" value="suit" id="suit" onkeypress="myFunction()">
                    <div><p class="producth6">Salwar-Suit<br /><span class="producth7">Rs. 675/-</span><br /><span class="producth8">onwords</span></p>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div style="height:80px;">
                <center>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10" style="float: none;display: inline-block;">

                    </div>
                </center> 
            </div>   
                 <p><button type="button" value="submit">Get Value of Selected</button></p>


        <!-- Div where i want to put the selected radio valur -->
    <div id="divID"></div>    
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `input` that you are trying to get returns true or false. You should get the actual element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use querySelector for javascript-

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
 function myFunction()
{
    var input = document.querySelector('input[name="garments"]:checked').value;
    var div = document.getElementById('divID');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + input+"<br>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: check this fiddle and remember to use myFunction on 'onchange' event-https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekcs139/enn3k5xz/1/

Comment: Thanks it is working but a little bit confusing. incase user selects suit and change mind and select t-shirt then your code shows both values. it should not be and I want to get value through submit button

Comment: For that you should use that function on submit button-
Check here https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekcs139/enn3k5xz/3/

Comment: @nadygold Did you get your point??
if yes choose your correct answer.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected radio button value you can use jQuery:
`$('[name=garments]:checked').val()`